# Vulnerability in using `input type="text"` for website password other than shoulder surfing

Tags: vulnerability, html

I found a website that uses the plain text field as a password input form.

`<input type = "text" autocomplete= off ...>`

I understand shoulder surfing is one vulnerability but are there other vulnerabilities that makes `input type="password"` a safer option?

Comment: One problem is that the browser will not propose to save the password. To me not having that choice is a loss in security (as saving pw is a security bonus but others believe it's a vuln).

Answer (score 8):

Beyond shoulder surfing the browser can insecurely cache data. It may save input fields in an insecure manner, for auto-fill purposes. This means passwords may be tab completed, easily retrieved as plain text, and copy/pasted.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, phones using a keyboard with 'next word' suggestion shortcuts will learn from your entry into text fields, but typically not password fields. If you have a password of common English words, it is very plausible that a phone will offer up the next word in your password if you type it, and have previously typed your password into a text field.

Only a serious issue if your phone is compromised or the database of your word predictions are compromised or shared insecurely (such as in a heuristic learning program that shares your phrases with the keyboard vendor for better learning)